# ReWriting Lucene Queries

Tags: lucene

I am a newbie and just started with lucene. I have a small issue. I need to know how to rewrite lucene queries. I read an article in (SO) where it was suggested to use
Query.rewrite ( the query rewriter turns higher-level query clauses into lower-level clauses that perform better. ). But for this it takes an object of type Index writer which i do not want to use.

Any suggestions for any other way to implement.

Thanks much in advance

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes an `IndexReader`, yes.  You can't rewrite an arbitrary query into primitive queries without an IndexReader, because the rewritten form depends on the terms in the index.  A `PrefixQuery`, for instance, will be rewritten into a set of `TermQueries`, based on which Terms in the index match the given prefix.  The `IndexReader` is needed to read those terms.  Without being able to read the current state of the index, [`MultiTermQueries`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiTermQuery.html), in general, can not be rewritten.